How to Customize Odoo 17 Sales Dashboard Using JSON in a Custom Module?
I am working with Odoo 17 and need to customize the sales dashboard by hiding specific sections. Here’s a brief overview of my current setup and what I’m trying to achieve:
Current Setup:Odoo Version: 17
Existing Configuration: The sales dashboard is configured in JSON format, referenced in an XML file like this:
<record id="spreadsheet_dashboard_sales" model="spreadsheet.dashboard">
    <field name="name">Sales</field>
    <field name="spreadsheet_binary_data" type="base64" file="spreadsheet_dashboard_sale/data/files/sales_dashboard.json"/>
    <field name="dashboard_group_id" ref="spreadsheet_dashboard.spreadsheet_dashboard_group_sales"/>
    <field name="group_ids" eval="[Command.link(ref('sales_team.group_sale_manager'))]"/>
    <field name="sequence">100</field>
</record>

Customization Goal:
I want to create a custom module to override the existing dashboard configuration and hide specific sections. I plan to achieve this by modifying the JSON file.
Questions:

How can I create a custom module to override the existing JSON configuration for the sales dashboard?

What is the correct approach to modify the JSON file to hide specific sections?

Are there any examples or best practices for working with JSON configurations in Odoo modules?


Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
